# Inconsistent yet true. What am I?

Tags: riddle

> High as a house
>
> But small as a mouse
>
> Smooth and shiny I'd say
>
> But so prickly you'll throw me away

What am I?

Hint:

> I am from Germany and someone actually told me this riddle in kindergarten on a beautiful day in autumn. It made a lot of sense to me back then.

Comment: This is the first riddle i posted. If you downvote please explain me why you do it. Also there is a legitimate answer.

Comment: I've downvoted this question because I think it follows a pattern that doesn't lend itself very well to high-interest riddles - primarily, it relies solely on recognizing an object by a few aspects of it that have been alluded to in individual lines. Riddles of this type tend to be straightforward to solve by recognition and prior knowledge alone, rather than pushing the reader for metaphorical reasoning.

Comment: (SPOILER) I disagree. If you look at the accepted answer you'll see, that this riddle does not describe only one object and its properties but rather 3 different objects which share a name and are closely related to each other. Simple recognition is not enough to solve this.

Comment: (SPOILER) I'm not sure I agree. "High as a house" refers to the fact that they grow high up. "Small as a mouse, smooth and shiny, prickly" is a list of adjectives describing the horse chestnut. "A beautiful Autumn day" directly describes the time of year they ripen. Each one of these is direct recognition of some aspect of the answer, and thus the answer relies primarily on straightforward recognition.

Comment: (SPOILER) I get what you mean and it could have been done better. But this riddle is (freely) translated from a german riddle and the hint is actually entirely true. I memorized it only because i liked the form which - at first - creates cognitive dissonance. I wouldn't have felt comfortable changing that.

Comment: In case anyone is interested. The original riddle is "Hoch wie ein Haus \\ Klein wie eine Maus \\ Glatt wie ein Spiegel \\ Stachlig wie ein Igel \\ Was bin ich?" which translates to "High as a house \\ Small as a mouse \\ Smooth like a mirror \\ Prickly like a hedgehog \\ What am I?". I was not able to determine the original author. I guess it is somewhat traditional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you:

> A Horse Chestnut?

High as a house

> Chestnut trees grow high

Small as a mouse, smooth and shiny, prickly

> Horse chestnuts are all of these.

A beautiful Autumn day

> They ripen in Autumn.

Comment: Correct! Very good.

Comment: Charlok's answer gave me the idea of something small up in a tree.

Comment: I don't recall even being discouraged by horse chestnut prickles, I recall them being soft, not fierce.

Comment: Depends. If they were dried it was entirely possible to get hurt. Also it depends on the specific kind. Fruits of the "Castanea sativa" for example are not so soft.

Answer (score 5):

I would guess you are

> An egg

High as a house

> In a nest

But small as a mouse

> A bird's egg would be small like that

Smooth and shiny I'd say

> An egg is smooth and perhaps shiny while whole

But so prickly you'll throw me away

> After it hatches one may throw away the (prickly) pieces

Comment: This is actually a really good idea, but there is a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess you are

> A cactus

High as a house

> [Cactuses have been known to grow near the tops of trees.](https://goo.gl/8lZuBg)

But small as a mouse

> [A single cactus is very small](https://goo.gl/2Wxtzk)

Smooth and shiny I'd say

> [Spineless cactuses are very smooth and sometimes even shiny](https://goo.gl/GgEPjC)

But so prickly you'll throw me away

> While cactuses are often grown as plants, they become very prickly and the owner—not wanting to get hurt—may well throw the cactus away.

Comment: Argh. This is good. Still not the answer. Somehow correct though.